# JQuery: dropdown list plugin HAVING customized scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I'm looking for a jquery plugin "dropdown list" HAVING a "customized scollbar" as in this site:(Field: select job category )

http://www.usatoday.com/money/careers/

1- Can anyone determine what plugin they use?

2- I tried to blind many plugins "dropdown lists" with many other plugins
 "customizable scrollbars" but in vain, for lack of solid knowledge in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is custom built by [Mark Kennedy](https://www.linkedin.com/in/markkennedy) for USATODAY.

```
             * @classdesc Used for adding dropdown functionality to &lt;select&gt;&lt;/select&gt; elements ONLY.<br/>
             * For dropdowns that are not select elements (i.e. divs or uls), the {@link ui/dropdown} should be used instead.
             * @author Mark Kennedy <mdkennedy@gannett.com>
             * @constructs form/dropdown
```

(Taken from dropdown.js within source code)

Comment: Is there similar free plugins that combine dropdown lists AND customizable scrollbar  ?